# Using a varying input to select values

Tags: python, loops, matrix, input

I have included part of my code below for reference. Essentially, I need to be able to choose the correct concentration values when a specific RH input is set. For example, if the RH were set to 0.2, I would need the concentration and activity values to be chosen automatically from the first row of each matrix. I am fairly inexperienced with coding, so this may be an easy fix,  but I'm a little lost on this. I would really appreciate any help!

```
RH = 0.8 #input any value from 0.2-0.9 with 0.1 steps 
OrgMF = 0.1 #no units - range from 0.1 to 0.9 - organic to sulfate mass fraction
Rc = 200*10**-9 #m (nm) - inorganic particle radius
Vinorg = 4*math.pi*(Rc**3)/3 #m3 - volume inorganic 
Minorg = Vinorg*1.5 #mass inorganic
Morg = Minorg/(1/OrgMF-1) #mass organic 
Vorg = Morg/0.9 #m3 - volume organic 
Vtot = Vinorg + Vorg #m3 - volume total
Rtot = (3*Vtot/4/math.pi)**(1/3) #m - radius total
Lorg = Rtot - Rc #m - thickness of organic coating
Ma = 0.1191390 #kg/mol - mass of IEPOX
Sa = 4*3.1415*((Rc+Lorg)**2) #m2 - surface area of particles 
Dg = 1e-4*0.1/Ptot #m2/s
a = 1 #no units - mass accomodation 
V = (4/3)*3.1415*((Rc+Lorg)**3) #m3 - particle vol 
T = 280.0 #K
R = 0.082057 #L*atm/k*mol 
R2 = 8.314 #j/k
Haq = 1*10**8 #M/atm - henrys law constant for IEPOX
Horg = 6*10**5 #M/atm - henry's law for org layer 
Dorg = 100*((1.38*10**-23)*T)/(6*3.1315*(5*10**5)*(315*10**-12)) #cm2/s - k*t/6*pi*viscosity*molecular radius - diffusion of IEPOX in org 
w = ((8*R2*T)/(3.1415*Ma))**0.5  #m/s - book equ for mean speed (281 in paper?)
kh = 3.6*(10**-2) #M-1s-1 - rate constant of H3O+ 
kso4 = 1*(10**-4) #M-1s-1 - ballpark - rate constant of nucleophile SO4-2 
khso4 = 7.3*(10**-4) #M-1s-1 rate consant of general acid HSO4-

#RH vs H concentration, activity
H_eaim = [[1.6*10**-5, 5.28*10**2], #RH 0.2 
          [1.67*10**-5, 1.6*10**2], #RH 0.3 
          [1.85*10**-5, 5.19*10**1], #RH 0.4
          [2.13*10**-5, 1.89*10**1], #RH 0.5 
          [2.53*10**-5, 7.41*10**0], #RH 0.6
          [3.07*10**-5, 3.1*10**0],  #RH 0.7
          [3.75*10**-5, 1.39*10**0], #RH 0.8
          [4.37*10**-5, 7.01*10**-1]] #RH 0.9
      
#RH vs HSO4 concentrations,  activity 
HSO4_eaim = [[8.4*10**-5, 1.97*10**0], 
             [8.33*10**-5, 1.89*10**0], 
             [8.15*10**-5, 1.81*10**0], 
             [7.87*10**-5, 1.7*10**0], 
             [7.47*10**-5, 1.55*10**0], 
             [6.93*10**-5, 1.37*10**0], 
             [6.25*10**-5, 1.14*10**0], 
             [5.63*10**-5, 8.49*10**-1]]

#RH vs SO4 concentrations, activity vs RH value 
SO4_eaim = [[1.6*10**-5, 6.09*10**-5], 
            [1.67*10**-5, 2.22*10**-4], 
            [1.85*10**-5, 6.25*10**-4], 
            [2.13*10**-5, 1.53*10**-3], 
            [2.53*10**-5, 3.02*10**-3], 
            [3.07*10**-5, 5.25*10**-3], 
            [3.75*10**-5, 8.3*10**-3], 
            [4.37*10**-5, 1.42*10**-2]]


H =  #M of H+ - EAIM CONCENTRATION - need to choose from the eaim values above for all M concentrations  
ah =  #EAIM ACTIVITY
         
SO4 = 3*10**-2 #M of nucleophile SO4-2 EAIM CONCENTRATION 
HSO4 = 1*10**0 #M of general acid HSO4- EAIM CONCENTRATION
         
Mt = 0.13615 #kg/mol mass of tetrol 
Ms = 0.216123 #kg/mol mass of sulfate product 
        
Htet = 1*10**8 #M/atm tetrol estimate  
Hs = 1*10**16 #M/atm sulfate product estimate
    
Kaq = (kh*H) + (kso4*SO4*ah) + (khso4*HSO4) #s-1 - reaction rate constant from gaston - using auto-selected eaim concentration/activity values to calculate
faqH = (kh*H)/Kaq
faqSO4 = ((kso4*SO4*ah) + (khso4*HSO4))/Kaq
```

Comment: Can you explain what the desired output is i mean is it a number an array try and show the structure of the expected result.

Comment: These concentrations are used to calculate a rate constant (Kaq) which is used in further equations & eventually goes into a diffeq solver. For this part, all I need is a single concentration value from each species for the specific RH input so that a Kaq can be calculated.

Comment: Hey the chemistry or biology you're doing is way out of my league or specialty, But i think i can help you with the code so here is my assumption  tell me if i'm right. I assume you want a function which accepts RH as an input whose value ranges between 0.2 and 0.9, and then and based on the value of RH you want the function to select the corresponding inner list from H_eaim which is a tuple containing concentration and activity at indexes 0 and 1 respectively and i also assume you want some validation for the input i.e RH. i will write your function if my assumption  is correct so let me know

Comment: Yes this seems correct! I mostly just need a starting point which I can definitely modify if it's not exactly I think, so I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

OK then, so in order to make your snippet work i had to do a couple of things:

1: import math at the beginning since its being used somewhere in the code and it was throwing an error. you should remove it when you combine it with you other code.

2: commented the Dg variable which is using Ptot which is not defined in the snippet.

3: i have initialized H and ah both with 0 so they dont throw an error and i also printed them bellow the function to see the result.

with that said i can think of two ways of doing it:

1st way is by using if elif else statements as bellow in the getConAct() function:

```
# k-devs added the line bellow
import math as math

RH = 0.8 #input any value from 0.2-0.9 with 0.1 steps 
OrgMF = 0.1 #no units - range from 0.1 to 0.9 - organic to sulfate mass fraction
Rc = 200*10**-9 #m (nm) - inorganic particle radius
Vinorg = 4*math.pi*(Rc**3)/3 #m3 - volume inorganic 
Minorg = Vinorg*1.5 #mass inorganic
Morg = Minorg/(1/OrgMF-1) #mass organic 
Vorg = Morg/0.9 #m3 - volume organic 
Vtot = Vinorg + Vorg #m3 - volume total
Rtot = (3*Vtot/4/math.pi)**(1/3) #m - radius total
Lorg = Rtot - Rc #m - thickness of organic coating
Ma = 0.1191390 #kg/mol - mass of IEPOX
Sa = 4*3.1415*((Rc+Lorg)**2) #m2 - surface area of particles 

# K-devs commented the line bellow 
#Dg = 1e-4*0.1/Ptot #m2/s
a = 1 #no units - mass accomodation 
V = (4/3)*3.1415*((Rc+Lorg)**3) #m3 - particle vol 
T = 280.0 #K
R = 0.082057 #L*atm/k*mol 
R2 = 8.314 #j/k
Haq = 1*10**8 #M/atm - henrys law constant for IEPOX
Horg = 6*10**5 #M/atm - henry's law for org layer 
Dorg = 100*((1.38*10**-23)*T)/(6*3.1315*(5*10**5)*(315*10**-12)) #cm2/s - k*t/6*pi*viscosity*molecular radius - diffusion of IEPOX in org 
w = ((8*R2*T)/(3.1415*Ma))**0.5  #m/s - book equ for mean speed (281 in paper?)
kh = 3.6*(10**-2) #M-1s-1 - rate constant of H3O+ 
kso4 = 1*(10**-4) #M-1s-1 - ballpark - rate constant of nucleophile SO4-2 
khso4 = 7.3*(10**-4) #M-1s-1 rate consant of general acid HSO4-

#RH vs H concentration, activity
H_eaim = [[1.6*10**-5, 5.28*10**2], #RH 0.2 
          [1.67*10**-5, 1.6*10**2], #RH 0.3 
          [1.85*10**-5, 5.19*10**1], #RH 0.4
          [2.13*10**-5, 1.89*10**1], #RH 0.5 
          [2.53*10**-5, 7.41*10**0], #RH 0.6
          [3.07*10**-5, 3.1*10**0],  #RH 0.7
          [3.75*10**-5, 1.39*10**0], #RH 0.8
          [4.37*10**-5, 7.01*10**-1]] #RH 0.9
      
#RH vs HSO4 concentrations,  activity 
HSO4_eaim = [[8.4*10**-5, 1.97*10**0], 
             [8.33*10**-5, 1.89*10**0], 
             [8.15*10**-5, 1.81*10**0], 
             [7.87*10**-5, 1.7*10**0], 
             [7.47*10**-5, 1.55*10**0], 
             [6.93*10**-5, 1.37*10**0], 
             [6.25*10**-5, 1.14*10**0], 
             [5.63*10**-5, 8.49*10**-1]]

#RH vs SO4 concentrations, activity vs RH value 
SO4_eaim = [[1.6*10**-5, 6.09*10**-5], 
            [1.67*10**-5, 2.22*10**-4], 
            [1.85*10**-5, 6.25*10**-4], 
            [2.13*10**-5, 1.53*10**-3], 
            [2.53*10**-5, 3.02*10**-3], 
            [3.07*10**-5, 5.25*10**-3], 
            [3.75*10**-5, 8.3*10**-3], 
            [4.37*10**-5, 1.42*10**-2]]

H = 0  #M of H+ - EAIM CONCENTRATION - need to choose from the eaim values above for all M concentrations  

ah = 0 #EAIM ACTIVITY


def getConAct(rh):
    global H
    global ah
    if rh < 0.2 or rh > 0.9:
        print('Wrong RH value!')
        return
    elif(rh == 0.2):
        [H, ah] = H_eaim[0]
    elif(rh == 0.3):
        [H, ah] = H_eaim[1]

    #put the rest of the elifs here

    elif(rh == 0.8):
        [H, ah] = H_eaim[6]
    else:
        [H, ah] = H_eaim[7]
    
getConAct(RH)
print('H = %f, ah = %f' %(H, ah))

SO4 = 3*10**-2 #M of nucleophile SO4-2 EAIM CONCENTRATION 
HSO4 = 1*10**0 #M of general acid HSO4- EAIM CONCENTRATION
         
Mt = 0.13615 #kg/mol mass of tetrol 
Ms = 0.216123 #kg/mol mass of sulfate product 
        
Htet = 1*10**8 #M/atm tetrol estimate  
Hs = 1*10**16 #M/atm sulfate product estimate

Kaq = (kh*H) + (kso4*SO4*ah) + (khso4*HSO4) #s-1 - reaction rate constant from gaston - using auto-selected eaim concentration/activity values to calculate

faqH = (kh*H)/Kaq

faqSO4 = ((kso4*SO4*ah) + (khso4*HSO4))/Kaq
```

Note : i have left some elif statements in the function i believe you can finish the rest by yourself.

2nd way is to modify the H_eaim list as bellow:

```
H_eaim = [[1.6*10**-5, 5.28*10**2, 0.2], #RH 0.2 
          [1.67*10**-5, 1.6*10**2, 0.3], #RH 0.3 
          [1.85*10**-5, 5.19*10**1, 0.4], #RH 0.4
          [2.13*10**-5, 1.89*10**1, 0.5], #RH 0.5 
          [2.53*10**-5, 7.41*10**0, 0.6], #RH 0.6
          [3.07*10**-5, 3.1*10**0, 0.7],  #RH 0.7
          [3.75*10**-5, 1.39*10**0, 0.8], #RH 0.8
          [4.37*10**-5, 7.01*10**-1, 0.9]] #RH 0.9
```

i.e adding the corresponding Rh value to each H ah tuple as a third item.

And then using the function bellow instead of the above one :

```
def getConAct(rh):
    global H
    global ah

for arr in H_eaim:
    if(rh in arr):
        H = arr[0]
        ah = arr[1]
    
getConAct(0.2)
print('H = %f, ah = %f' %(H, ah))
```

- if you don't want to modify H_eaim use the 1st way. if that's OK then the 2nd one looks better!

Note: i have noticed that python performs some rounding as of now i do not know how to prevent it.

the rounding is something like 0.0469 to 0.047.

if that's going to be an issue i suggest that you look into it.

Good Luck!

Comment: thank you for the help! I think I can get this to work now. Rounding shouldn't be too much of an issue

Comment: Glad i could help, And  If you require further assistance along the way here is my email : kaleabaalemu@gmail.com you can contact me i'm up for a job!